# Type or namespace of 'ModelBuilder' cannot be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In [step 7 of the ASP.MVC 3 Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc3-part7-cs), it introduces the 'ModelBuilder' type. I'm using ASP.Net 4, MVC 3, and EF 4.1, and I get the red squiggly lines under the 'ModelBuilder' type. It can't find the type. Has that type name changed? What reference should I add to use it?

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Movie>().Property(p => p.Price).HasPrecision(18, 2);
    }
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The name changed from CTP5 to EF 4.1. This thing is now called `DbModelBuilder`.

Comment: This appears to be the route to go as far as the tutorial is concerned. Worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.data.schema.schemamodel.modelbuilder.aspx) that is still a good class.  It's located in  `Microsoft.Data.Schema.SchemaModel`.

I just tested this and I had no problems.  You need to make sure you add a reference in your project to the the assembly listed at the MSDN link.  The assembly is `Microsoft.Data.Scheme.dll`.  Then in your code you need a using `Microsoft.Data.Schema.SchemaModel`.