# how can i solve : the type or namespace name 'DbModelBuilder' Could not be found

Tags: asp.net

i created an MVC Project for test on another PC last night
it worked good on that PC but when i want to build it on my own PC it i give error : 
the type or namespace name 'DbModelBuilder' Could not be found(are you missing...)
how can i solve it ?

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.Edm.Db;

namespace University.Models
{
    public class SchoolContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this dll exist in your solution? 
If it points to DbModelBuilder.dll in a folder in the other PC, it won't run successfully in your PC.

Edit:

Can you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450463/type-or-namespace-of-modelbuilder-cannot-be-found-are-you-missing-a-using-dir) ?

Comment: You know this is just toturial on ASP.NET/MVC Toturials, Chapter 4, when i was creating project on other PC i didn't add any reference. Do you know about DbModelBuilder ? read the mvc toturials chapter 4, on the first lesson. thanks a lot

Comment: My EntityFramework on other pc was 4.1 but on this Pc was 4.0 i downloaded and installed 4.1 version it solved my problem, thanks all :-x

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot an assembly reference to `System.Data.Entity`.

Comment: at the first i guessed i should add a reference to EntityFramework.dll but it didnt solve my problem(i had referenced i deleted and added again)